# TextField vaadin java

Tags: java, vaadin

Первый TextField работает как надо, с остальными что-то не так, они не редакируются

[image: Screenshot]

В коде типа:

```
disabledField.setEnabled(false);
```

или

```
readonlyField.setLabel("Read-only");
```

нет, что это может быть?

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

```
disabledField.setEnabled(false);
```

метод `setEnabled` устанавливает состояние поля ввода.

- `setEnabled(false)` - делает поле неактивным(нередактируемым в том
  числе)
- `setEnabled(true)` - делает поле активным (данное значение, является значением по умолчанию)

Соответственно, в коде Вам необходимо убрать `setEnabled(false)`, на полях, которые должны быть редактируемыми.

```
readonlyField.setLabel("Read-only");
```

Изменяет только заголовок поля.
Соответственно, данный метод просто выводит надпись "Read-only" перед вашим полем.
На поведение поле данный метод никак не влияет.